# Object destructuring with Short-Circuit Evaluation

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring, object-destructuring, short-circuit-evaluation

Is it possible to do achieve something like this?

```
const obj1 = { name: 'tom' }
const obj2 = { age: 20 }

let { name, age } = obj1 || obj2
```

**Getting as a result -> name = 'tom' and age=20**

The code above doesn't work, as it evaluates the condition one time and not on each variable assignment, which of course makes sense. It evaluates to name='tom', age=undefined

Is there any way to make that logic work?

Thanks!

Comment: Object destructuring works against a single object only (with that syntax). You must merge the two objects first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the objects and then try to destructure like:

```js
const obj1 = { name: 'tom' }
const obj2 = { age: 20 }

let { name, age } = {...obj1, ...obj2}; 
console.log( name, age )
```

Comment: Makes complete sense, don't know why I didn't think about this before haha. Thanks! Will accept the answer as soon as the site allows me to

Comment: This is my preferred method. Works quite well. You can also have duplicate keys and the objects listed later can override the earlier ones. You can have an object with all the defaults as the first object, then have one or more with the non-default values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by

```
  let { name, age } = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)
```

This first create an object that has all the attributes of obj1 and the attributes of obj2.

Note this does not deeply copy attributes.

Comment: Yep, just saw it on the previous answer. Thanks!